# How to build Boost 1.57 for Windows Phone 8 with Visual Studio 2013 Pro?

Tags: windows-phone-8, boost, visual-studio-2013, compilation, b2

I want to build Boost 1.57 for Windows Phone 8 but when I run b2 like so

```
b2 toolset=msvc-12.0 variant=release architecture=arm windows-api=phone
```

I get strange errors similar to this one for every target

```
'/Zm800' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

My guess is that the build system has not set the compiler properly. It compiles without errors using b2 like so

```
b2 toolset=msvc-12.0 variant=release
```

What am I missing? How to compile Boost for Windows Phone 8?

Comment: Yes, I'm going to provide an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It seems there is a directory missing in Visual Studio 2013. The solution is to download and copy the files that come with this [blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/07/18/using-boost-libraries-in-windows-store-and-phone-applications.aspx) to the right place:

> Please note Visual Studio 2013 didn’t include vcvarsphone setup scripts so you won’t be able to target Phone 8.1 out of the box. With this blog post I’ve included phone setup scripts that can be used when targeting Windows Phone 8.1. To setup them up create the folders called WPSDK\WP81 under the VC Visual Studio installation directory, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\`, and copy the phone setup script files in.

[BoostSample.zip](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-10-54-33-32/BoostSample-.zip)

Comment: Anyway, I tried to build as in the blog, and I get a errors like this:  fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/thread/futures/is_future_type.hpp': No such file or directory. did this also happened to you?

Comment: I got errors during build, but I don't think this one because I have the following binaries: atomic, chrono, date_time, exception, math, serialization, signals, system, and thread.